# Converting multiple datetime formats in single column to standard datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
df.datetime.head()

0    03 Mar 2023 00:00 ## Its a 24 hr format
1    03 Mar 2023 00:00
2    03 Mar 2023 00:00
3    03 Mar 2023 00:00
5    03 Mar 2023 00:00
6    2020-02-07 00:00:00
7    2020-02-02 22:00:00
8    2020-02-02 00:00:00
9    2020-02-02 22:00:00
```

How do i convert this column to a standard datetime format?

when I do

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

I get this error:

```
 raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 03 Mar 2023 90+ '
```

when I do

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], errors='coerce')
```

I get

```
0    2023-03-03
1    2023-03-03
2    2023-03-03
3    2023-03-03
5    2023-03-03
6    2020-02-07 00:00:00
7    2020-02-02 22:00:00
8    2020-02-02 00:00:00
9    2020-02-02 22:00:00
```

I lose the time part of the date.

```
desired format --> 2020-02-02 22:00:00
```

Some of the vlaues are lost as NaT completely in conversion.

What is the most effienct and appropriate way to convert these multiple datetime formats to a standard format?

Comment: Try `df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: I did. Then I lose the timestamp. I would like the timestamp as well because its there in the input column just in a different format. Its a 24 hr format

Comment: I tried with your dataset and get correct result.

Comment: it can be beacuse of 00:00, try to replace df.datetime = df.datetime.str.replace('00:00', '00:00:00')  and then to apply pd.to_datetime

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['03 Mar 2023 00:00', '03 Mar 2023 00:00', '03 Mar 2023 00:00',
                            '03 Mar 2023 00:00', '03 Mar 2023 00:00', '2020-02-07 00:00:00',
                            '2020-02-02 22:00:00', '2020-02-02 00:00:00', '2020-02-02 22:00:00']})


r = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

print(r)
```

```
0   2023-03-03 00:00:00
1   2023-03-03 00:00:00
2   2023-03-03 00:00:00
3   2023-03-03 00:00:00
4   2023-03-03 00:00:00
5   2020-02-07 00:00:00
6   2020-02-02 22:00:00
7   2020-02-02 00:00:00
8   2020-02-02 22:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```